# Removing Visual Studio 2010's upgrade of SP1 after removing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was removing my windows 7's updates from the Control Panel but after that when I tried opening Visual Studio 2010, it didn't opened, I wanted to reinstall it so I un-installed visual studio first but after that when I tried to remove it's SP1 update it was not allowing it, re installation is giving a error that a software with the same key exisits

Comment: Well, I'd guess you are never going to do *that* again.  Maybe a restore point will work, odds are not that great.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). This software can do a deep analysis of installed software. IT first try to uninstall the product using the official uninstaller, then seek remaining files and registry keys.

Use with cautious, because it can remove more than necessary.